# How to find out if card was declined in Braintree Payments

Tags: swift, braintree

Im currently using braintree as my payment system for my app the issue im having is that that I have no way of finding out if the card was declined or accepted before it proceed to another viewcontroller please take a look at my current function. Thank you in advance.

```
func postNonceToServer(paymentMethodNonce: String) {

        let paymentURL = NSURL(string: "http://salesandsolutionsplus.com/braintree_php_api/public_html/checkout.php")!

        let postAmount = formInfo["servicePrice"]!

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: paymentURL)
        request.HTTPBody = "payment_method_nonce=\(paymentMethodNonce)&amount=\(postAmount)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            // TODO: Handle success or failure

            let dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
            let value = self.formInfo


            if error != nil {


                print(error)

                return
            }





            dbRef.child("streetServices/Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(value, withCompletionBlock: { (error, fir) in
                if error != nil {

                    print("alert error")
                    print(error)

                    return
                }

                // present confirmation after payment process
                let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vc3") as! ConfirmationViewController

                self.presentViewController(next, animated: true, completion: nil)

            })


        }.resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

The [result object](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/result-objects/php) from a `Braintree_Transaction` contains a `success` attribute that will either be true or false. Depending on the value of `success`, you will either have a [transaction_result](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction/php) or an [error result](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/result-objects/php#error-results) to give you more information. Once this reponse is parsed in your server side code, you can send it to the client any way you choose.